# Debug connection to another domain from aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, digital-ocean, droplet

I have a problem connecting to a droplet on digitalocean from lambda. The problem is that this lambda connects to the internet without any problem. I can connect to any other domain, just not digitalocean. How can I debug this connection? Is there any way to run MTR or traceroute from lambda?

My setup: AWS lambda in a private network, connects to the Internet via NAT gateway. On lambda I have code in nest.js

The droplet is open to the internet. I can connect to it locally and from ec2 instance. But every attempt to connect from lambda ends with a timeout.

I tried changing the zones in which I ran the droplet and lambda. The effect is the same. I tried removing the firewall completely. Unfortunately it doesn't help

I've tried connecting to other domains and it always works. We use many integrations in our project.